# Importing cell data from other excel documents

Tags: excel, vba, import, paste, freeze

I am trying to create a macro which takes horizontal data from ImportTestFile and pastes it into another file vertically using the new files format. The data in ImportTestFile may become longer as it is updated (which is why I used the count).

My problem is that I get an error whenever I use Paste special, and when I just use ActiveSheet.Paste the excel file i'm importing into it stops allowing me to click on cells. 
Eventually, I want to copy multiple lines of data from ImportTestFile but for now i'm just trying to get one line right first.

ImportTestFile is 2.3Mb, if you think that is the reason for the clicking problems do you know a way I could still import data from it without this problem occurring?

```
Sub copydata()
Dim erow, eColumn As Long, rowUsed As Long, lastcolumn As Long, firstColumn As Long
Dim managerName, managerLetter, fileName, fileLocation, fileType As String

Workbooks.Open fileName:="/Users/james/Desktop/ImportTestFile.xlsx"
Worksheets(1).Select
rowUsed = 28
firstColumn = 4
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(28, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(rowUsed, firstColumn), Cells(rowUsed, lastcolumn)).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Worksheets(1).Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @james code seems to be fine try closing other opened excel files and try.

Comment: I created a new excel document and added this code to it then ran it and it still had errors with the ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial but the feezing/ clicking problems did disappear.